# Toggling debug mode programmatically

Tags: c#, debugging, asp.net-mvc-4, web-config

Is it possible to put a parameter or a variable to MVC 4 Web config file, so I can set debug mode true:false during runtime or after release?

Or can I do it in code?

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by 'debug mode'? If you mean enabling debugging symbols / disabling compiler optimizations, no. If you mean hooking into a VS debugger instance, then sometimes. If you mean turning on certain trouble shooting features such as custom error messages, then yes.

Comment: yes, getting custom error messages and error stacktrace. What an admin needs, but user doesnt have to see

Comment: do you mean `#if debug`/`#endif`? added to code in similar way to a `#region`

Comment: the goal is to be able to turn debugging on/off from GUI.

Comment: sounds like you'll have to encorporate your own boolean into your program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If permissions on your IIS server are set to allow changes to web.config from your site's code you can relatively easy do so. You can use XML API to change Web.config.

Notes:

- it is bad idea to allow site's code to modify it configuration/binaries. Make sure you understand security implication of that
- your site will restart on any change to web.config, for normal sites (stateless, all date is in some sort of external storage/DB) it is somewhat ok, but if you have something like in-memory session state it could be painful. Even stateless servers may require significant time to start - be careful.

You should consider other approaches (i.e. simply logging and reading logs server side) before starting to play with configuration of servers if they actually see real user traffic and especially internet traffic.

Comment: I see, thanks for the warnings (+1). I'll keep it just during the development. Any ideas how to implement XML to web config?

Comment: @Goran303 - there are tons of "how to read XML, change attribute value and save it back" samples... try to search. If you can't find one - feel free to ask as separate question...